# Is a [DataMember] that is a byte array in a WCF contract a security hazard?

Tags: wcf, buffer-overflow

Am I exposing my service to a buffer overflow attack?  If so how would you defend against this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just my own insight: No, the managed code is not susceptible to overrun attacks, and the unmanaged portions of the transport channel are dealing with byte-arrays anyway.